# Possible to share Tmobile Internet using my Android (Moto Z2 Play NO ROOT) via a USBC > Ethernet > Laptop?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, 7.1-nougat, usb-tethering

Looking for a way to bypass my hotspot limit as I keep hitting the 10GB cap on Tmobile. Is there a way to share internet directly from my android phone (moto z2 play NO ROOT) plugged into a usbc > ethernet adapter then to my laptop's ethernet port? Does android 7.1 even have the ability to route the internet into this ethernet port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an app called [pdanet+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet) to share hotspot through WiFi, or usbc cable.

All you have to do, is download the app onto your phone, and also download it onto your laptop from [here](http://pdanet.co/install). You will then be able to open the app, in your phone, and enable usb tethering, it will then give you specific instructions on how to proceed depending on your device.

No root required, and it works for me even though my carrier doesn't allow hotspot at all!

(You should also select "hide tether usage", so that your carrier doesn't know your used hotspot at all)

[image]

Comment: 2018-March -- verified working on my moto z2 play on tmobile! Installed pdanet on my android 7.1 and then installed the windows pdanet software then let it detect your phone and set usb debugging on in the android. From there just check off USB sharing on the android and activate it on the desktop aswell. thanks!